# Need another help to show up text on the screen dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, d3.js

Now i got this second problem using d3.js that i cannot solve by my own. I got a dynamic array "path" which length always changes when i click on. Then i got a "text" variable at a starting position on the svg (112, 490).
With the help of you guys, i now use the for-loop to show the names of the "path" array based on it's switching length on the console and it worked. But now i want the names to appear on the screen. But my

```
 textNode.attr("dx", 112 + i*2);
```

line does not work. I want the text shift right on the x-scale starting at the point 112 a little bit with each node.

This is the text

```
var text = svg.append("text")
.attr("dx", 112)
.attr("dy", 490)
.text("1. Node: " )
```

and this is the for loop

```
for (var i=0;i<path.length;i++) {
text.attr("dx", 112 + i*2);
text.text( +i+1+". Node: " + path[i].name);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very basic principle in D3: **don't** use loops, such as a `for` loop, to show or display the data (sometimes we do use loops, but in very specific and complex situations, not this one). In your other question, the proposed solution used loops because there was no `d3.js` tag in the question. But using a loop like this makes little sense if you're using D3. It's an entire library created to manipulate data, and you're ignoring its most important aspect.

Instead of that, **bind** your data to a selection. In your case, as your array is constantly changing, you're gonna need an "enter", "update" and "exit" selections.

First, bind your data:

```
var texts = svg.selectAll(".texts")
    .data(data);
```

Then, set the selections:

```
textsExit = texts.exit().remove();

textsEnter = texts.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "texts");

textsUpdate = texts.merge(textsEnter)
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", (d, i) => i * 16)
    .text(d => d.name);
```

Here is a demo to show you how it works. I have an data array, which length changes every second:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var dataset = [{
    name: "foo"
}, {
    name: "bar"
}, {
    name: "baz"
}, {
    name: "lorem"
}, {
    name: "ipsum"
}, {
    name: "dolot"
}, {
    name: "amet"
}];

print(dataset);

setInterval(()=> {
    var data = dataset.slice(Math.random() * 6);
    print(data);
}, 1000);

function print(data) {

    var texts = svg.selectAll(".texts")
        .data(data);

    textsExit = texts.exit().remove();

    textsEnter = texts.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "texts");

    textsUpdate = texts.merge(textsEnter).attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", (d, i) => 20 + i * 16)
        .text((d,i) => "Node " + (i+1) + ", name: " + d.name);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow, this really helps!! thanks so much to both of you!! @sam: looks like you also didn't know that using loops in d3.js is not good? :)

Comment: Totally forgot about that, good call Gerado! This should be the answer. Yes, I've used selectAll and Bind myself but totally forgot about that part of d3js.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is incorrect for your specific use case, but I think you want to do "x" instead of "dx". That's how I've moved objects to the left / right in d3.js:

```
textNode.attr("x", 112 + i*2);
```

EDIT: here's an example that adds text objects and moves them to the right based on the index:

```
for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    var text = svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", 112 + i*2)
        .attr("y", 490)
        .text("1. Node: " )
}
```

**EDIT2: See Gerardo's answer. D3js has its own methods for binding and looping through data.**

Comment: hey sam, i think you are right, but my plan was not to move the object. I want to create new text object based on the length of the array.

Comment: This can be done, you just have to append, then modify the x attribute:

var text = svg.append("text").attr("x", 112);

You could put that in your for loop, so it will both create new objects and move them to the right. Just add the "+ i*2" if you do.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Can you explain how you would put it in the loop? How to use the counter i right?

Comment: I edited my answer showing how you would both add and move the elements to the right.

Comment: You mean just to directly paste it in the loop?                                            for (var i=0;i<path.length;i++) {
 var text = svg.append("text").attr("x", 112 + i*2)
text.text( +i+1+". Node: " + path[i].name);

Comment: Thanks Sam, that really works! I changed the last line into                            .text("1. Node: " + path[i].name )  and it looks nice, but the problem is, that the value does not change or update when i click around on the  nodes (changing the values and length of the array)