# How to add a click event or mouseover on dynamic elements ( enter/update/exit )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

based on this example:
[Need another help to show up text on the screen dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898253/need-another-help-to-show-up-text-on-the-screen-dynamically)

it is possible to let elements (for example a text) in D3.js appear and disappear with the help of the enter/update/exit rule.

```
 var texts = svg.selectAll(".texts")
        .data(data);

    textsExit = texts.exit().remove();

    textsEnter = texts.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "texts");

    textsUpdate = texts.merge(textsEnter).attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", (d, i) => 20 + i * 16)
        .text((d,i) => "Node " + (i+1) + ", name: " + d.name);
```

Now i want to add a click event or a mouseover on the appearing text elements. So i tried to add a mouseover first and changed the `textsUpdate`part into:

```
     textsUpdate = texts.merge(textsEnter).attr("x", 10)
     .attr("y", (d, i) => 20 + i * 16)
      .text((d,i) => "Node " + (i+1) + ", name: " + d.name)
  .on("mouseover", function(d){ this.style.fill == "blue"});
```

The goal is that everytime when i move the mouse over the newly appereared elements, then they should turn blue.
Unfortunally this did not worked well. Can someone help and give me a hint about the missing thing?

Thanks

Comment: `this.style.fill == "blue"}`: shouldn't it be `this.style.fill = "blue";}`?

Comment: you are right, it worked. Can you post in a way i can accept your answer? currently i cannot accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

You are stopping your access to textUpdate after you access .text(...) and before you access with .on(...). There is an extra semicolon before .on.

Comment: Hey, i just edited the part with the extra semicolon. But the rest looks fine for me. And it also works on the original post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898253/need-another-help-to-show-up-text-on-the-screen-dynamically