# Enter, update, exit with rectangles?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, rectangles

Based on this question: [Need another help to show up text on the screen dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898253/need-another-help-to-show-up-text-on-the-screen-dynamically)

it is possible to enter, update and exit elements dynamically in D3.js. In the code below it is possible to to this with texts.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var dataset = [{
    name: "foo"
}, {
    name: "bar"
}, {
    name: "baz"
}, {
    name: "lorem"
}, {
    name: "ipsum"
}, {
    name: "dolot"
}, {
    name: "amet"
}];

print(dataset);

setInterval(()=> {
    var data = dataset.slice(Math.random() * 6);
    print(data);
}, 1000);

function print(data) {

    var texts = svg.selectAll(".texts")
        .data(data);

    textsExit = texts.exit().remove();

    textsEnter = texts.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "texts");

    textsUpdate = texts.merge(textsEnter).attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", (d, i) => 20 + i * 16)
        .text((d,i) => "Node " + (i+1) + ", name: " + d.name);

}
```

Now, i tried the same thing with circles and it worked fine. Then i tried to do this with rectangles and it did not work. Here is the code for the rectangle example:

```
 var rect= svg.selectAll(".rect") 
             .data(path1);

            rectExit = rect.exit().remove();

            rectEnter = rect.enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "rect");

            rectUpdate = rect.merge(rectEnter)
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return (10 + i * 2)})
            .attr("y", 12)
            .attr("width", 10)
            .attr("height", 40)
            .attr('stroke', "blue")
```

Can someone help me maybe?
Thanks

Comment: Hello, Derick, I'm not understanding this question: your code **is** working: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/7qtw1vkr/

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the hint.